# add_rewrite_rule parameter is not received by the page

Tags: rewrite-rules

This doesn't work:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^spor/?','index.php?pagename=search&search_text=spor',top);
```

It goes to the search page but `search_text=spor` is not taking effect.  (Like Empty)

When I manually browse from browser:

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php?pagename=search&search_text=spor
```

the query works succesfully. What am I  missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom query vars have to be added via the `query_vars` filter to be parsed within rules.

```
function wpd_add_query_vars( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'search_text';
  return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_add_query_vars' );
```

You can then get the value with `get_query_var('search_text')`.